# Overlapping error message when trying to log in to Area 51

Tags: bug, area-51, login, openid

I was trying to log in to Area 51 using my **Stack Exchange** email/password, but I got an error overlapping most of the screen (the green bars were randomly added by me, not by aliens, in case there is a security risk at sharing those values):

[image]

Note: No issue to log in to other planets of the Stack Exchange universe (like https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).

I wish two things:

1. Please help me to log in to Area 51
2. Please improve the display of the error message

I use:

- Chrome 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- MacOS Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73)
- China Telecom